# NFS mount groups

Tags: systemd, nfs

I have a number of servers which mount a series of NFS mount points.  The groupings of exports used for those mount points defines a 'personality' for each server.  Each 'personality' tends to include a number of identical mount points, but also include a few unique mount points.

This is accomplished typically by storing a unique fstab for each personality (Actually using Ansible to add the group of mounts to each server).

What I'd like to provide for my users is a way for them to switch the server NFS personalities on demand (Without rebooting if possible), while still maintaining control over the personalities via Ansible.  I'm sure there's a million ways to approach this, but I'd like to poll for a few more common techniques if there are any.

- Should I try to use an fstab based approach?
- Is there a better way to do this using systemd targets?
- Some other tool in RHEL7/8 land that is better suited?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly. But if your goal is to allow Mary have some mounts, while John have another set of mounts, then...

It is easy-ish to do.

1. Create a file (or files) with allowed mount points and addresses, you can mimic fstab structure too. The real `/etc/fstab` would be used for common mounts and controlled by root only. So for users, you can do something like:

```
# /etc/fstab.user/mary
10.0.0.40:/source-repo repository nfs
```

```
# /etc/fstab.user/john
//server/Secret-Documents documents cifs
```

2. Add into `/etc/profile` (or its equivalent called for each user) a code like:

```
if [ -e /etc/fstab.user/$USER ] ; then
   while read device dir tp
   do
      mkdir -p /home/$USER/mnt/$dir
      mount -t $tp $device /home/$USER/mnt/$dir 
   done < /etc/fstab.user/$USER
fi
```

So, each user would have its own set of mounts in `$HOME/mnt/` And the actual root will have control over who is getting what.

This approach works fine even when the actual folder `/etc/fstab.users` is by itself is mounted from the network.

Comment: That's not what I was going for exactly.  The switching between personalities would be system wide and controlled by users belonging to allowed groups.  Most of the mountpoints would also be the same (But pointing to different exports).  All users would have to use the same mounts once switched.

Your idea does give me some ideas I hadn't yet considered which might solve other user-specific issues (A profile based selection).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use .target units to start and stop mounts – for example, if you put a group of .mount units in personality-one.target, the user could `systemctl enable` or disable the entire target at once. (Though *stopping* a target and having this propagate to its "child" units might need more work, possibly a "StopWhenUnneeded=" in each .mount unit.)

However, consider using the `autofs` automounter. Its main job *is* to manage groups of NFS mounts. (It also has the advantage that the mounts it manages are "on-demand", so if you have 200 hosts mounting 200 filesystems each, rebooting them doesn't overwhelm the file servers with thousands of mount requests all at once.)

If each group of mounts is under the same directory (e.g. all of them are subdirectories of /data), you can define that entire directory as an automount map (e.g. /etc/auto.data) which is then referenced from the "master" map (/etc/auto.master). Standalone mounts which don't fit into this structure can be defined through a "direct" map. For example:

- Master map, which can be tailored for this host:

  ```
  # cat /etc/auto.master

  /data   /etc/auto.data
  /tools  /etc/auto.tools
  /-      /etc/auto.direct
  ```
- Automount map for a group of mounts under `/data` (/data/one, /data/two, etc):

  ```
  # cat /etc/auto.data

  one     -nosuid,nodev datahost.example.com:/exports/data_one
  two     -nosuid,nodev datahost.example.com:/exports/data_two
  ```
- Automount map for "direct" mounts (all over the place):

  ```
  # cat /etc/auto.direct

  /opt/sometool    filehost.example.com:/exports/software/sometool
  /var/backup      filehost.example.com:/exports/backups/$HOST
  ```

  (If you've ever used systemd .automount units, they rely on the same autofs feature and work very much like a 'direct' automount map.)

Starting the automount service will then mount an "autofs" virtual filesystem at /data – which will *seem* to be empty initially, but as soon as a subdirectory such as /data/one is **accessed** by any program, it will be mounted from the corresponding NFS share.

You can deploy all maps via Ansible and symlink one of the available master maps to "/etc/auto.master". Users will be able to switch host personalities by re-symlinking e.g. "/etc/dist/auto.master.groupA" to the master map and reloading the automount daemon, which will automatically add or remove the autofs mounts that it manages.

(The auto.master file can also include "drop-ins" from a directory using a special entry such as `+dir:/etc/auto.master.d/`, so users could symlink smaller pieces if there's a need to have a mixed systems.)

Comment: I hadn't considered an autofs approach because we've so-far avoided autofs due to the latency the on-demand mounting causes (Some of my use cases require the low latency of an established mount).  It's something I can easily experiment with.I'm going to study this as well as the systemd target approach.  Glad I posted this question and thanks for the idea!

Comment: Disable the autofs idle-unmount timeout and the latency impact should become minimal (once per mount per reconfig).

Comment: I've been trying to get systemd working for this, but it's been frustrating.  My basic issue is that systemd requires the name of the mount file to be based on the name of the mountpoint itself.  If mount/automount filenames were arbitrary, then I could use targets to control groupings of mounts with different sources but to the same mountpoints.  I've got another thread going concerning how to get SYSTEMD_UNIT_PATH working, but even that is proving to be difficult given my use of RHEL7.

Comment: I didn't realize the groups will have contradictory definitions of the same paths. In that case, either use a systemd *generator* (even a simple one that just copies the appropriate units out of /usr/share/foo to /run upon daemon-reload), or use autofs maps.

Comment: Another engineer is working on the autofs approach.  The generator approach is my next avenue of investigation.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Another option I forgot was to have a tool that acts like a "manual generator" by symlinking the appropriate units from /usr/foo/$personality into /etc/systemd (and starting them through the .target, as before), as systemd supports units symlinked from an outside location. Not very nice but I think that's still a level above the "patching mounts into /etc/fstab" last-resort option.

Comment: I tried the manual generator approach using a simple bash script.  It copies the mount/automount files from the personality into /run/systemd/generator.  A target is used as an intermediate dependency (To remote-fs.target) so that all of my mounts are 'WantedBy' and 'PartOf' that target rather than directly being part of remote-fs.target. It looks like it should serve my purpose.  There's probably a lot of gotchas with dependencies to ensure the mounts start and stop properly.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a few rounds of iteration with systemd mount and automount units grouped by a master target unit, I found I was getting wrapped up in the dependencies and various options needed to replicate the behavior that the normal fstab generator already provides.

For the many (Nearly 50) mountpoints per 'personality', the entire effort became too cumbersome to continue.  So, I backed up and wrote a python tool which takes entire sections of fstab entries (Blocked by keywords) and effectively un-comments those while commenting out blocks for fstab entries of other groups.  A server reboot then forces the fstab generator to rebuild the units.

The server personality can then be switched and the server rebooted by authorized admins using the new tool.

The lesson learned is that one should not attempt to re-implement something as complex as the systemd fstab generator.  I certainly learned a lot about how it works but for the number of mountpoints I have and the myriad of dependencies (One mount depends on another, automount, etc..) the ease of being able to specify things in fstab is too beneficial to ignore.  The simplicity of being able to manage a single master fstab (blockinfile) within Ansible, rather than 100's of unit files, is also too great to ignore.

To be sure, if the fstab generator had a way to generate units from an arbitrary input file (fstab) and output to an arbitrary path which could be combined with the systemd search paths (Not of those are possible in my RHEL7 environment), a different solution might have been possible.

Thank you all for your inputs!